# Two equivalent Working Copies in xCode project

Tags: xcode, git

In my project I suddenly got two equivalent Woking Copies

[image]

In file xcshareddata/1f-messenger.xccheckout I see duplicates. But as I understand this file
is made at each opening of the project and it is useless to try to modify it.

The most annoying thing is that when I try to pull data from remote git xCode shows me two equivalent repositories one of which is forbidden because of local code change until a commit.

I suspect that problem is due to some path corruption. One can see the fragment of 1f-messenger.xccheckout

```
<key>IDESourceControlProjectRelativeInstallPathDictionary</key>
<dict>
    <key>9CAC6304-4358-41CD-9DFC-AAB679FD18F6</key>
    <string>../../../../../../../../users/malex/Work/Git/1Forma/1f-messenger</string>
    <key>CE5489EB-6E76-493B-AD14-F8FB23B31539</key>
    <string>../..</string>
</dict>
```

I monitored all git configs, made new clone of my repo. But it seems that this is a problem of xCode itself.

The problem arose when I made a copy of the project locally and opened copy in xCode.
Now I have no any project copies on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is amazing but this problem is cured by ordinary osx reboot!
Note that reopen of xCode even after project "delete" and "clone" doesn't affect situation.